# How to sort 2d array column wise and row wise for given columns and rows by users

Tags: c, sorting

guys, this is my first time in stackoverflow
I want to sort array of random numbers row wise and column wise
after this I have to search for a given key but I am stocked in
the first part.
the problem is user should choose  dimension of array between (2-5000) and elements in array is between (4-25 milion) and each element can be from 0 until int MAX and number of column and row is equal to each other
I found good code but I did not understand how to change it in order to satisfy the limit of my programm I tried to #define my 2d array like this

## define R 5000

## define C 5000

but it is wrong
this is the code I am trying to write

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define R 500
#define C 500

void sort_rows(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        int key=arr[i];
        int j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && key<arr[j])
        {
            arr[j+1]=arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1]=key;
    }
}
void sort_column(int arr[500][500],int c)
{
    int key,k;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<c;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<c;j++)
        {
            key=arr[j][i];
            k=j-1;
            while(k>=0 && arr[k][i]>key)
            {
                arr[k+1][i]=arr[k][i];
                k--;
            }
            arr[k+1][i]=key;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int arr[R][C];
    int r,c;
    int i,j,size_row,size_column;
    printf("Enter Number of rows and columns(2-5000)");
    scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            arr[i][j]=rand()%(r*c)+1;
    }
    printf("Original array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    size_row=((sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0][0])/(sizeof(arr[0])/sizeof(arr[0][0]))));
    printf("%d",size_row);
        for(i=0;i<size_row;i++)
    {
        sort_rows(arr[i],sizeof(arr[i])/sizeof(arr[i][0]));
    }
        size_column=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    for(i=0;i<size_column;i++)
    {
        sort_column(arr,size_column);
    }
    printf("Sorted Array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

any help would be great

Comment: Unless this is an assignment, you may want to use `qsort()` which is already included in stdlib.h.

Comment: actually, this is an assignment thanks for your comment but i need exactly help on this one

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your array with R and C that you defined with #define, but you read new values, r and c, from user and work on it.

You should define your array dimensions  with the values you will use.

Also, you have passed an integer to sort_column which considered as call by value, but you should pass array pointer to be able to edit your array, and that is call by reference.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I tried to scanf("%d%d,&R,&C) but It did not work and I tried  pass to pointer my sort_column(arr,size_column) void sort_column(int *arr,int c)

Comment: would you please modify some part of this code that you think is wrong and paste it here that would be really helpful

Comment: You can't edit #define value. If you want to take array dimensions from user by scanf, then you don't need to #define C and R. I mean don't use both. For calling by reference, for two dimensional array you need to do: sort_column(int **arr, int c).

Comment: OK thank you now its ok but still whole program does not work

Answer (score 0):

- You usually can't. A 50000x50000 2D array has 50000x50000x(`int` size) bits.

  This is (with `int` size equals 4 bytes) 10 GB of memory, more than your system usually allows.

  The are ways to change OS limits, but it is easier in this case to make your array global.
- This code has a lot of awkward lines that look either unnecessary or wrong, so I've shortened and changed it a little to make it work like intended to.
- Keep in mind that these functions you got are running [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort), a pretty inefficient sorting algorithm (O(n^2)). The program will take A LOT of time to run with big instances. You might want to look for better algorithms, like [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort) and [quick sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).

Modified algorithm:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define R 50000
#define C 50000

int arr[R][C];
void sort_rows(int *arr,int n)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        int key=arr[i];
        int j=i-1;
        while(j>=0 && key<arr[j])
        {
            arr[j+1]=arr[j];
            j--;
        }
        arr[j+1]=key;
    }
}
void sort_column(int arr[][C],int r,int c)
{
    int key,k;
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<c;j++)
        {
            key=arr[j][i];
            k=j-1;
            while(k>=0 && arr[k][i]>key)
            {
                arr[k+1][i]=arr[k][i];
                k--;
            }
            arr[k+1][i]=key;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int r,c;
    int i,j,size_row,size_column;
    printf("Enter Number of rows and columns(2-%d,2-%d)",R,C);
    scanf("%d%d",&r,&c);
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
            arr[i][j]=rand()%(r*c)+1;
    }
    printf("Original array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        sort_rows(arr[i],c);
    }
    sort_column(arr,r,c);
    printf("Sorted Array:\n");
    for(i=0;i<r;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<c;j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",arr[i][j]);

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: wow amazing thank you so much actually I am not still ok with C but this made my life easy